# Filtering/reordering an existing WP Query with new parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to limit the amount of queries called on a page, and have two similar arg sets that are being displayed in different areas:

```
        $recent_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'cat' => 941,
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );

        $trending_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'cat' => 941,
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'meta_key' => 'custom_post_views_count',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
```

How can I only perform this query once, but in the actual display have it reorder based on the different params?

Answer (score 0):

Please use if else condition like this

```
$data = 1;
if($data == 1)
{
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'cat' => 941,
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
}
else
{
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'cat' => 941,
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'meta_key' => 'custom_post_views_count',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
}
$query_result = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still result in two queries to the db?

Comment: This way only one query run at a time.. so , thats why only one request pass to db and receive actual result.